# Get this error : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" when i call a function trough onclick

Tags: javascript, html, templates

i get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

When i click on this :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="newsGenerator({{link}})" class="blog-more">READ MORE</a>
```

This function is refer to this :

```
function newsGenerator(contents) {
  var newsSelected = window.open("");
  newsSelected.document.write(contents);
}
```

The {{link}} that you see on the "a href" come from here :

```
link: "<html><head><title>MyTitle</title></head><body>test</body></html>",
```

That is built on my template like this :

```
template = template.replace("{{link}}", item.link);
```

With the function :

```
var html = ""

assets.forEach(buildTemplate);
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = html;

function buildTemplate(item) {
  var template = document.getElementById("template").innerHTML;
  template = template.replace("{{name}}", item.name);
  template = template.replace("{{date}}", item.date);
  template = template.replace("{{publisher}}", item.publisher);
  template = template.replace("{{link}}", item.link);
  template = template.replace("{{info}}", item.info);
  template = template.replace("{{img}}", item.img);
  html += template;
}
```

Comment: Your link looks like HTML not a URL string.

Comment: Yes i called it a link but it can be "dog" it doesn't matter how i call it

Comment: lol. You could call it dog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `link` with additional escaped single quotes. Something like this:

`link: "\'<html><head><title>MyTitle</title></head><body>test</body></html>\'"`

Comment: No need to escape single quotes in double quotes.

Comment: yup. it worked!! i knew that it was someting about the formatting but i didn't find the solution for my case around. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is the JavaScript you are generating.

```
newsGenerator(<html><head><title>MyTitle</title></head><body>test</body></html>)
```

You can't have a `<` operator immediately after the `(` that starts a function call.

It looks like you are trying to pass a string.

String literals must be delimited with quote marks or apostrophes.

(Remember that your HTML `onclick` attribute value is currently delimited with quote marks).